# Is it possible to bind not to a property of an element but the element itself in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

`TransformA` is a TranslateTransform, I would like to do something like this:

```
<Setter Property="RenderTransform">
  <Setter.Value>
    <TransformGroup>
      <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
      <TranslateTransform Self="{Binding TransformA}"/>  
    </TransformGroup>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Is there another way to achieve this?

---

I know I can bind a single `RenderTransform` like this

```
<Path RenderTransform="{Binding TransformA}"/>
```

with a Setter

```
<Setter Property="RenderTransform" Value="{Binding TransformA}"/>
```

or multiple transformations with a TransformGroup

```
<Setter Property="RenderTransform">
  <Setter.Value>
    <TransformGroup>
      <TranslateTransform X="5" Y="5"/>
      <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
    </TransformGroup>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Ash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1506454/ash)'s answer, this is not possible. I instead got it to work by creating a new `TransformGroup` in codebehind and binding that

Codebehind:

```
public TransformGroup combinedTransformGroup {
  get {
    var transformGroup = new TransformGroup();
    if (TransformA != null)
      transformGroup.Children.Add(TransformA);
    transformGroup.Children.Add(new RotateTransform(90));
    return transformGroup;
    }
    set { }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Setter Property="RenderTransform" Value="{Binding combinedTransformGroup}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Binding cannot replace target object. You can use MultiValueConverter - to combine multiple tranforms into one TransformGroup:

```
public class TransformGroupConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var tg = new TransformGroup();

        foreach(Transform t in values.OfType<Transform>())
        {
            tg.Children.Add(t);
        }

        tg.Freeze();

        return tg;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

here is modification of xaml markup with fixed RotateTransform and bindable 
TransformA:

```
<Setter Property="RenderTransform">
    <Setter.Value>
        <MultiBinding>
            <MultiBinding.Converter>
                <local:TransformGroupConverter/>
            </MultiBinding.Converter>

            <Binding>
                <Binding.Source>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                </Binding.Source>
            </Binding>

            <Binding Path="TransformA"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

---

or simply bind individual properties:

```
<TranslateTransform X="{Binding TransformA.X}" Y="{Binding TransformA.Y}"/>
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but got an error for ```tg.freeze()```. I got around it by creating the TransferGroup in codebehind and then bound the transfergroup.